# PHP Newbie - I need to do a case insensitive directory file search

Tags: php

```
<?php
//--- get all the directories

$dirname = '//10.9.0.215/images/';
//--- $dirname = 'Images';

$findme  = $_POST["ImageName"];
$dirs    = glob($dirname.'*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
$files   = array();

echo '<img src="logo.jpg"/><br><br>';
echo '<a href="index.html">Return Home</a><br><br>';
echo "<b>--- List of Images Found ---</b><br><br>";

//--- search through each folder for the file
//--- append results to $files

foreach( $dirs as $d ) {
    $f = glob( $d .'/'. $findme );
    if( count( $f ) ) {
        $files = array_merge( $files, $f );
    }
}

if( count($files) ) {
    foreach( $files as $f ) {      
echo "<a href='{$f}'>{$f}</a><br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "Image not found.";//Tell the user nothing was found.
//--- echo '<img src="yourimagehere.jpg"/>';//Display an image, when nothing was found.
}

?>
```

Comment: and the problem with the code posted is ???

Comment: Hi @williams and welcome on SO. You need to format your code if you want people help you.

Comment: you would also actually need to formulate your question, and explain *where* you have a problem.

Comment: Still trying to figure out this site so please bear with me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you change your pattern to this:

```
$dirname = '//10.9.0.215/[Ii][Mm][Aa][Gg][Ee][Ss]/';
```

you should be able to matach any case variation of **images**

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply but I tried that and I got no records found. Please advise

Comment: tested here, works fine, sure about that path (//10.9.0.215)?

Comment: I noticed that you removed the /images in  $dirname = '//10.9.0.215/[Ii][Mm][Aa][Gg][Ee][Ss]/'; is that correct? because the whole path is $dirname = '//10.9.0.215/images/[Ii][Mm][Aa][Gg][Ee][Ss]/'; please advise and thanks for all your help